# How to pass value to textbox in grid view using JavaScript by popup window?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get selected textbox index? How to get access of particular row?

```
var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID%>");  
for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {  
    var txtAmountReceive = $("input[id*=TextBox2]")
    txtAmountReceive[i].value="hello"
    txtAmountReceive[i].Text = "hello";
    var popup = window.open("Default3.aspx", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
    document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').Text = "hello";
        popup.focus();
}
```

Comment: can u be more specific on what u need

Comment: i nedd a popup from which i enter a value in grid viewsfor specific row

Comment: Here you go http://techbrij.com/show-modal-popup-edit-aspdotnet-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans: How to get access of particular row

```
protected void ShowPolicy_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == ("Proceed"))
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int currentRowIndex = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                txtBoxId.Text = Convert.ToString(ShowPolicy.DataKeys[currentRowIndex].Value);
                txtAnotherBox.Text =  Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text)
                //Similarly you can do for other cells.

            }
        }
```

File.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ShowPolicy" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 

            onrowcommand="ShowPolicy_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="PolicyNumber">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonProceed" runat="server" Text="ProceedToEdit" CommandName="Proceed"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PolicyNumber") %>'/>


            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understand your popup page and grid view page both are different.

If you want to pass value from one page to another page using javascript then you can use `localStorage`

Default3.aspx

```
localStorage.setItem("KeyForAccess", "YourValue");
```

Gridview page

```
var txtAmountReceive = $("input[id*=TextBox2]")

txtAmountReceive[i].value=localStorage.getItem("KeyForAccess");

txtAmountReceive[i].Text =localStorage.getItem("KeyForAccess");
```

FYI : It will require HTML5